# Facebook comment box is over riding

Tags: php, html, css, facebook

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/Societ%C3%A0-Ginnastica-Triestina-Nautica/149520068540338" data-width="270" data-num-posts="3">
```

This comment box is over riding my div height and going on my footer any solution to limit the comments and it should not over ride

Answer (score 0):

Add to your div display:block; and clear: both; if this doesnt fix it, post a jsfiddle with your code so I can see what it is doing. You may also want to implement sticky footers as well.

Comment: <div class="fb_box"  style="display:block;clear:both;">
          <div class="left_blue_strip"  >{{$lang_var_name.facebook}}</div>
         <div id="fb-root" ></div>
       <div class="fb-comments" style="display:block;clear:both;" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/Societ%C3%A0-Ginnastica-Triestina-Nautica/149520068540338
" data-width="270" data-num-posts="1">

</div>
         </div>

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=00000000000";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>

Comment: Can you post a link to your site so I can see what it is doing?

Comment: I had this very same problem on a site where my elements could not see the other elements. So im not sure as to why its breaking.